# Unable to delete GeoTIFF after adding it to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

After adding a file to GeoServer via REST I am unable to delete it from the directory on my computer. I always get the same error saying that the file is in use by another process.

This only happens when apply a style to it that will show the layer as a contour map.

I have tried removing the layer from GeoServer but the GeoTIFF will remain in use anyway.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [known bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9349), it probably only occurs on windows machines and as such is unlikely to get much developer traction as none of the core developers is a windows user during their volunteer time.

You can either fix this yourself and submit a PR with the fix or pay someone to fix it for you.